# Trying to copy a file using RandomAccessFile in Java

Tags: java

i am trying to copy a simple .txt data using RandomAccessFile in Java. I´ve coded the following program:

My Main Method:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    File original = new File("C:\\Users\\Tjatte\\Documents\\testdatei.txt");
    File copy = new File("C:\\Users\\Tjatte\\Documents\\testdateicopy.txt");
    copy(original,copy);
}
```

My static copy method

```
public static void copy(File main,File copy){
    try{
        RandomAccessFile data = new RandomAccessFile(main,"rw");
        RandomAccessFile datacopy = new RandomAccessFile(copy,"rw");

        datacopy.seek(0);
        for(int i = 0; i < main.length(); i++){
            datacopy.write(data.read());
            data.skipBytes(i);
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
    }
}
```

Whenever i want to copy a file with the text "hello" in it, the output in the copied file is "halÿÿ"... But it has to be "hello".

I appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check it out [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/file/4-ways-to-copy-file-in-java/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't skip bytes. Seems like "read" operation will move the pointer to the next character automatically.

So, just delete the line with "data.skipBytes(i);"

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Can you accept the answer then?

Comment: Yes sure... took me a while to find it but here we go :)

Comment: It "seems" like?? Read the javadoc of [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html): *input operations read bytes starting at the file pointer and **advance the file pointer past the bytes read***

Comment: Also, copying a file one byte at a time is very slow. You should use the [`read(byte[] b)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#read%28byte[]%29) and [`write(byte[] b, int off, int len)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#write%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) methods, with a `byte[]` buffer of appropriate size, e.g. 4k.

Comment: Andreas, i tried your idea and it works, expect one thing.... When i use a buffer of 4k, even if i only have like 100 letters, its printing so much white space in my .txt data and because of it. In the end, the file copy is bigger than the original one.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer [`Files.copy(Path, OutputStream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) and a [`try-with-resources` close](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) like

```
public static void copy(File main, File copy) {
    try (OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(copy)) {
        Files.copy(main.toPath(), fos);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**or**, as pointed out by [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas) in the comments, use [`Files.copy(Path, Path, CopyOption...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) like

```
try {
    Files.copy(main.toPath(), copy.toPath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why not use the [`Files.copy(Path source, Path target)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) method?

Comment: Yea, normally i wouldve tried another solution instead of RandomAccessFile.. But my assignment for university was limited on RandomAccessFile.. :)

Comment: @Andreas I forgot that the vararg was optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can this way too:

```
public class CopyFileContent{

    static final String FILEPATH = "C:../../inputfile.txt";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {

            System.out.println(new String(readFromFile(FILEPATH, 150, 23)));

            writeToFile(FILEPATH, "Hello", 22);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static byte[] readFromFile(String filePath, int position, int size)
            throws IOException {

        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
        file.seek(position);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        file.read(bytes);
        file.close();
        return bytes;

    }

    private static void writeToFile(String filePath, String data, int position)
            throws IOException {

        RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "rw");
        file.seek(position);
        file.write(data.getBytes());
        file.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your work, appreciate it. Right now i am at the beginning of Streams, but your effort will help myself to improve!

Comment: Please up vote if my solution is correct as it would help others with similar problem

Comment: ye i did but i have not enough reputations at the moment. :/